# Navigation menu is hoverable but it is not displaying WordPress

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation

The menu is there it is hoverable but you cant see it. I have tried every possible soltuion but it is not working.

Comment: Could you share your tried solutions so we can see what you did?, once we know what you tried/trying to do we can help.

Comment: Actually i found the solution its the opacity whenever i go to inspect element and change the opacity to 10 the items appears but when i goto theme editor to save it permanently it doesnt effect

Comment: @QasimYousaf Since you solved it, please close or self-answer this question.